# What does 'tracking=1' in a URL mean?

Tags: url

I noticed the string `'tracking=1'` in a URL link today and got wondering what exactly it means and I can't seem to find anywhere what this actually means.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing special in any parameter in general.

It totally is up to the application that handles that request on what semantics it puts to the requests with such a parameter.